# Gmail conversation view but how do I prevent it for a specific email?

Tags: gmail

Say I have a CRM system which sends 20 emails to a single gmail account.

When sent all 20 emails come to Gmail inbox as a "Conversation" since they are coming from a single email.

I can switch off conversation view in Gmail settings to prevent this from happening.

But how do I do it so say if I sent 20 emails at once from my CRM systems email (e.g: admin@somedomain.co.uk they get delivered separately but without SWITCHING OFF the conversation view. So it works for other emails but not the CRM systems email.

Answer (score 7):

Gmail will consider emails as art of the same conversion based on the [subject line](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=5900)

> A conversation will break off into a new thread if the subject line of the conversation is changed, or if the conversation reaches over 100 messages.

Therefor tweak the CRM to avoid identical subject lines.